# Changing TabView: Resize TabView & Window

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I made an application which have a preferences window with 2 tabs.
The first tab have a lots of prefs settings in it, but the second one is very small...

I'd like that the tabview & the window resize when we switch between these 2 tabs.

I act like that, but it doesn't seems to work, when I switch view the "Networks settings" tab is being reduced and disapear (like if the height was going from origin to 0 with animation).

Here is my code (.m):

```
- (void)tabView:(NSTabView *)tabView
didSelectTabViewItem:(NSTabViewItem *)tabViewItem
{
    NSRect  frame;
    int    height;

    if ([[tabViewItem identifier] isEqualTo:@"Panel settings"]) {
        height = 400;

    } else if ([[tabViewItem identifier] isEqualTo:@"Network settings"]) {
        height = 200;

    } 

    frame = [[tabView window] frame];

    frame.size.height = height;
    frame.origin.y += height;

    [[tabView window] setFrame:frame display:YES animate:YES];
}
```

Note that I linked the tab view to delegate.
My window is linked to the NSWindow * PrefWindow referencing outlet.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you set the resizing behavior in IB so that the tabView resizes vertically with the window?

Answer (score 0):

I still think the problem is with the way your springs and struts are set in IB -- make sure you set them for not only for the tab view itself, but also for the individual objects in the view of the tab view item.  I noticed that the default settings for my subviews had them all with the top strut set which made any subviews near the bottom of the view disappear when the window shrunk.

Comment: I checked all the view, tab and window resize options but the entire window still "disapear" (animated way). :/

Comment: @Nono,Try commenting out that last line that resets the window frame and resize the window by dragging the corner and see what happens. Being slower, this should let you see better what happens when the window shrinks (or if it happens at all under these conditions).